# What is the derivative of $F[\mathbf{v}]=\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}$?

Tags: derivatives

How does one attack a derivative of this type?

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial (\mathbf{v})} \mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial (\mathbf{v})} \mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}&=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial (\mathbf{v})} \mathbf{v}^T\right)\mathbf{v}+ \mathbf{v}^T \frac{\partial }{\partial (\mathbf{v})} \mathbf{v}\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial (\mathbf{v})} \mathbf{v}^T\right)\mathbf{v}+ \mathbf{v}^T
\end{align}
$$

I am uncertain how to treat the part $\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial (\mathbf{v})} \mathbf{v}^T\right)\mathbf{v}$?

Is $\mathbf{v}^T$ constant with respect to $\mathbf{v}$? --- doubtfull.

What is then the derivative of a transpose of a vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\nabla(\mathbf v^T\mathbf v)=\nabla(x^2+y^2+z^2)=2(x\,\mathbf i+y\,\mathbf j+z\,\mathbf k)=2\,\mathbf v.$$